# Azure: cloned disk, can't bring online

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

I have an Azure server on which I now realize I'm paying a fortune for a 1TB SSD, when in reality I only need about 400GB of HDD.

I took a snapshot of the SSD and stored it in Azure, then created a new HDD. Azure wouldn't let me make the new disk smaller than 1 TB, since that was the snapshot size, so...OK, at least I'll save on HDD vs SSD.

So I attached this new drive to my server, but now for some reason I can't bring it online:

[image]

"Access denied"?! But I'm the guy who created it, and I'm logged in as a Windows admin.

Maybe it's a conflict with the drive letter? My current drive is labeled `F:`, so maybe the snapshot also wants to force this new drive to be `F:`? So I tried detaching the existing drive, but that didn't help, either.

So, how do I attach this drive? (Bonus points if you can tell me how to shrink the size of the new disk, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's an easy way to change the disk from SSD to HDD, if you're using managed disks. Just shut down the VM, then in the Azure console, open the disk and select "configuration":

[image]

(Note: I took this snapshot while my VM was running, so it's disabled here, but this was really simple to do in the end.)